# Элементарный Git script

Tags: shell, git

Стоит винда. Запускаю гит баш. при каждом запуске надо переходить в определенную директорию. набирать руками не хочу.  
Пробовал написать скрипт

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /d/Coding/Angry_coders/Repository
ECHO 'hi'
```

при запуске. hi выводит а cd не делает.

Comment: Так, наверное, потому что cd происходит в убиваемой экземпляре консоли. Вставьте команду `pwd` и убедитесь, что все правильно переходится в экземпляре командного интерпретатора, который исполняет шелл-скрипт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Решение 1.**

Запускать шелл-скрипт через .
Например, у нас шелл-скрипт называется 1.d и лежит в домашнем каталоге.

```
gaal@linux-lybs:~> . 1.d
/usr/bin
hi
gaal@linux-lybs:/usr/bin>
```

**Решение 2.**

Создать [алиас](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(bash)) в файле настроек командного интерпретатора. Можно еще пойти через создание [функции](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500499/how-do-you-call-a-function-defined-in-bashrc-from-the-shell)

Answer (score 0):

В свойствах ярлыка помимо "Объект" - программа, которая запускается, есть еще "Рабочая папка". Вот в неё скопировать путь к Вашему проекту - и он автоматически открывается при запуске гита с ярлыка (git v.1.8.3)